# Acceptable Actors to use in a BPMN diagram?

Tags: workflow, actor, diagram, bpmn

I'm trying to model a User Account creation process whereby an Admin goes about creating a new User Account.

Is it acceptable to have Actors who are of a different type in a BPMN/Swim Lane diagram?

So for example, the Actors in this case are 'Client Administrator' and 'Software Portal System'.

My ex manager says you're not supposed to mix an 'Actor' who is the person performing an activity with an Actor of a different type (i.e. software system).

I, of course, think he is wrong as I've seen BPMN diagrams with a human Actor and software/hardware systems interfacing each other before.

i.e. here: http://blog.joget.org/2012/04/joget-workflow-v3-part-1-process-design.html

I'm looking for guidance from the Stakeoverlow brains trust.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason as to why this has been downvoted? I think this is a perfectly reasonable question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "different type in a BPMN/Swim Lane diagram". Could you create an example diagram for that rather than linking some weird diagrams in a blog?

Comment: Example Actors: Payroll Consultant, Super Administrator, Payroll Software Product

Comment: So is the question whether the above can go in a single diagram in different lanes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BPMN provides Pools for modeling actors, which represent roles, like 'Client Administrator', or specific *agents* such as organizations (like Amazon in processes involving Amazon) or IT systems.

The BPMN 2.0 specification (in *9.2 Pool and Participant* on p. 112) says:

> A Pool is the graphical representation of a Participant in a Collaboration. A Participant can be a specific PartnerEntity (e.g., a company) or can be a more general PartnerRole (e.g., a buyer, seller, or manufacturer).

Answer (score 0):

As first: we use BPMN for Computation Independent Model (see MDA omg.org), mean: no system lines in models ;)

Second: any form (e.g. application form) have to be modeled (e.g. as a UML structured classifier, see composite structure diagram in UML).

Suggest design process as a status oriented (application form workflow) and all details pus as a rules to form fields.